# Killing Supervisord doesn't kill sub-processes

Tags: linux, supervisord

I am using supervisord to run my packages and scripts. However when I kill the supervisord process, one of the child process goes to the init and is still running. Below i the sample of the supervisord.conf file that I am using:

```
[program:foo]
command=/bin/cat
stopsignal=KILL
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true

[program:foo1]
command=/usr/bin/python2.7 /home/lab/example1.py
stopsignal=KILL
killasgroup=true
stopasgroup=true
```

I am trying to give `stopsignal=KILL` and `killasgroup=true` and `stopasgroup=true` also but to no avail.
How to fix this?